# Pseudo-class in selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

The following HTML markup

```
<div id="child">
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

and CSS stylesheet

```
input[type="text"]:focus{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#child {
    border: 10px solid grey;
    border: 20px black solid;
    background: aqua;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

are given. But I want the effect of applying both `hover` and `focus` pseudo-classes. I think that copy-paste of code like this:

```
input[type="text"]:focus{
    border: 1px solid green;
}

input[type="text"]:hover{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

isn’t a best way, because it's very upsize code. Is there a way to do it without applying JS?

Comment: You mean like.. `input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="text"]:focus {}` ?

Comment: `:focus` and `:hover` are pseudo-classes, not pseudo-elements (I edited it in your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that helps to reduce your code by having a single style block for multiple selectos, in your case:

```
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="text"]:hover
{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```